# dotnet core logging using AddTraceSource is not working

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, .net-core

Debug Logging is working, but I cannot get TraceSource to work.
This is supposed to be simple, right? :)

My `AppSettings.json" is looking like this...

```
"Logging": {
   "IncludeScopes": false,
   "LogLevel": {
   "Default": "Information"
   },
   "Debug": {
     "LogLevel": {
       "Default": "Information"
     }
   },
   "Console": {
     "LogLevel": {
       "Default": "Information"
     }
   }
 }
```

My `Startup` is looking like this...

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    // add Trace Source logging
    SourceSwitch sourceSwitch = new SourceSwitch("sourceSwitch", "Logging Sample")
    {
        Level = SourceLevels.Information
    };

    loggerFactory.AddTraceSource(sourceSwitch, new TextWriterTraceListener(@"C:\temp\trace.log"));

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

And my sample controller is looking like that...

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<ValuesController> _logger;
    private readonly ILogger _logger2;

    public ValuesController(ILogger<ValuesController> logger, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _logger2 = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("sourceSwitch");
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task Get()
    {
        string myName = "demo";
        _logger.LogError($"{myName} started.");
        _logger2.LogError($"logger2 {myName} started.");

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        _logger.LogInformation($"{myName} finished.");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately no file is being written (to).
File permissions are not an issue. I can use `File.AppendAllText()` without any issues.

Also I couldn't find any meaningful documentation regarding the `SourceSwitch` and the importance of its name. I basically followed the official documentation outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#tracesource-provider

Answer (score 2):

For `AddTraceSource`, it is not supported under `.NET Core`, you need to target your project to `.NET Framework` if you want to use `AddTraceSource`.

> to use this provider, an application has to run on the .NET Framework (rather than .NET Core). The provider lets you route messages to a variety of listeners, such as the TextWriterTraceListener used in the sample application.

Reference:   [TraceSource provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#tracesource-provider)

For check this behaivor, you could try to follow steps below:

1. Edit csproj

   ```
    <TargetFramework>net47</TargetFramework>
   ```
2. Since `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` is not compatible with net47, reference the required refernece directly:

   ```
     <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="7.5.0" />
   <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.6" />-->
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.0.6" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.3" />
   <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.8.3" />
   <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.4.*" />
   <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.4.*" />
   <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.4.*" />
   <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.4.*" />
     </ItemGroup>
   ```
3. Build and run your project to check whether file is created.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, maybe that's the reason...

https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#tracesource-provider

> To use this provider, an application has to run on the .NET Framework (rather than .NET Core).

Comment: Yes, that's it. You could try my suggestion to check how it will work with .net framework.

Comment: uh --- but you can build netstandard2.0 libraries that use TraceSource, so how do you make the application log to that ?